# Can one carry a child outside an eruv on Shabbat?

Tags: shabbat, children-parenting, hotzaa-carrying-reshuyot

If one is on a walk on Shabbat with a small child in an area without an eruv, and the child gets tired, is one allowed to carry the child? For the purpose of answering this question, assume that the child is not in any danger, is just getting fussy, and does not have anything in his or her pockets.

Answer (score 6):

### Kitzur Shlchan Aruch

The Kitzur Shlchan Aruch in [סימן פב - אסור העברה והוצאה מרשות לרשות](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00561.html#HtmpReportNum0081_L2) **explicitly forbids it.**

It's irrelevant if the child can already walk or not.

> **סעיף י'**: הָאִשָּׁה מְדַדָּה אֶת בְּנָהּ אֲפִלּוּ בִּרְשׁוּת הָרַבִּים, וּבִלְבַד שֶׁלֹּא תִּגְרְרֵהוּ, אֶלָּא יְהֵא מַגְבִּיהַּ רַגְלוֹ הָאַחַת וְיַנִּיחַ הַשְּׁנִיָּה עַל הָאָרֶץ וְיִשָּׁעֵן עָלֶיהָ עַד שֶׁיַּחֲזוֹר וְיַנִּיחַ רַגְלוֹ שֶׁהִגְבִּיהַּ, שֶׁנִּמְצָא לְעוֹלָם הוּא נִשְׁעָן עַל רַגְלוֹ הָאֶחָת. אֲבָל כְּשֶׁהִיא גּוֹרֶרֶת שְׁתֵּי רַגְלָיו הֲרֵי זֶה כְּנוֹשֵֹאתוֹ וְאָסוּר אֲפִלּוּ בְּכַרְמְלִית. **וְלָשֵּׂאת אוֹתוֹ מַמָּשׁ אֲפִלּוּ אִם הוּא גָּדוֹל כָּל כָּךְ שֶׁיָּכוֹל לֵילֵךְ בְּרַגְלָיו לְבַדּוֹ, אָסוּר אֲפִלּוּ בְּכַרְמְלִית, שֶׁלֹּא אָמְרוּ הַחַי נוֹשֵׂא אֶת עַצְמוֹ אֶלָּא לִפְטוֹר מֵחַטָּאת.** אֲבָל עַל כָּל פָּנִים שְׁבוּת אִכָּא, וּבְכַרְמְלִית הִיא שְׁבוּת דּשְׁבוּת, **וּצְרִיכִין לְהַזְהִיר לָרַבִּים, שֶׁטּוֹעִין בָּזֶה** (שֻלְחָן עָרוּךְ שֶׁל הַתַּנְיָא סִימָן שח סָעִיף פא. וְעַיֵּן תְּשׁוּבַת ר' עֲקִיבא אֵיגֶר סִימָן כח). ‏

He explains that the concept of הַחַי נוֹשֵׂא אֶת עַצְמוֹ - *a live entity carries itself* - means that one who carries a live entity will not have to bring a sacrifice. But he has still transgressed a שְׁבוּת - *a Rabbinic decree* - regarding Shabbat.

### Aruch HaShulchan

The Aruch HaShulchan in [סימן שח - דיני מוקצות ונולד](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01582.html#HtmpReportNum0226_L2) goes a step further and even forbids "walking the kid" unless he is capable of walking by himself.

His reasoning is that if he can't walk by himself, then you've transgressed a Torah prohibition if you accidentally pick him up.

> **סז**: והאשה מדדה את בנה אפילו ברשות הרבים, והיינו כשמגביה רגל אחת ומניח רגל אחת, דבכהני גווני אפילו תגביהנו - חי נושא את עצמו. **ובלבד שלא יהא קטן כל כך שגורר רגליו**, דבכהני גווני לא אמרינן 'חי נושא את עצמו', ויש בזה חיוב חטאת אם תגביהנו.
>
> ולכן אם הוא כפות או חולה, אפילו גדול – אסור, ואפילו בכרמלית אסור לגוררו, דזהו כנושא ממש. אבל כשמגביה רגלו אחת ומניח רגל אחת והוא בריא ואינו כפות – מותר, דכשנשען עליה לעולם רגלו אחת על הארץ, ורק רגלו האחרת נגבה מעל הארץ, וסומך על אמו.
>
> (והמאור סובר דגם במגביה רגל אחת חייב אם נושאו ואינו נושא את עצמו, אלא שמכל מקום משום צער התינוק לא גזרו שמא יגביהנו, ולפי זה גם בגורר מותר, כיון דחד דינא אית להו, והרי אינו כן וצע''ג, ודבריו הם בריש פרק נוטל והובא במג''א סקע''א. ומ''ש המג''א בדין כיס תלוי בצואר תינוק, כבר בארנו זה בסימן ש''א, שבשם נתבארו כל דיני הוצאה) ‏

### Kitzur Sh"A Yalkut Yosef

The Kitzur Sh"A Yalkut Yosef in [דיני חבישת מכה בשבת](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01355_part_22.html#HtmpReportNum0140_L2) allows one to carry a child who is unwell **to get medical attention** on Shabbat, if he is capable of walking by himself, but he finds it difficult [due to his medical condition].

Even though normally it's forbidden, since it's only a שְׁבוּת  - *a Rabbinic decree* - and since the child isn't well, the decree does not apply.

> **קז** ילד חולה שצריך לקחתו לרופא בשבת, אם הוא יכול ללכת בכוחות עצמו, אלא שההליכה קשה עליו, מותר לשאתו ברשות הרבים, גם במקומות שאין בהם עירוב. [דחי נושא עצמו, והוי איסור דרבנן, והכא אי אפשר לעשות כן בשינוי]. אבל אם אינו יכול ללכת בעצמו אסור לשאתו ברשות הרבים. ובמקום חשש פיקוח נפש, מותר בכל אופן. אך יש להזהר היכא דאפשר שבשעה שמרים את הילד לא יהיה עליו או בכיסו חפץ כל שהוא. [ילקוט יוסף שבת ד' עמוד קפב]. ‏

All agree that in case of danger to life, one may carry a child - and do anything else needed to prevent loss of life.

Comment: How do you understand: וּבְכַרְמְלִית הִיא שְׁבוּת דּשְׁבוּת?  It sounds as if he is saying that there is no problem in a carmelis?  (I thought שְׁבוּת דּשְׁבוּת is not classified as a Shabbos violation?)

Comment: @SamGoldberg שְׁבוּת דּשְׁבוּת afaik is okay only in certain circumstances not outright.

Comment: @SamGoldberg, as msh210 already said, שְׁבוּת דּשְׁבוּת is classified as a Shabbos violation, except in special cases like שבות דשבות במקום מצוה. See http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%95%D7%AA for an overview (Wikipedia is not a Posek, obviously.)

Comment: Note that the conditions in the question may render the child a Choleh sheEin Bo Sakana as the issue of his location is affecting his ability to function normally, and carrying him home is the 'medical' solution to his 'Choli'. Your answer is speaking more abstractly than the question's case (which is fine, except you don't clarify that you are doing so).

Comment: So if I take my kid to the park on Shabbat, if I can't verbally convince him to leave, and am unwilling to leave him in the park unsupervised, I am stuck there for the balance of Shabbat?  If my kid sits down on the sidewalk, there we stay until 3 stars come out?

Comment: @Ze'evFelsen - Yes. Point being? (And if your kid turns off the lights then you sit in the dark. And if you run late on Friday you get out the vehicle in the middle of nowhere and stay there for 25 hours. And if your plane is delayed you sit in the airport until Motzai. So?)

Answer (score -2):

The Halacha is that because the child is able to walk, you're allowed to carry him. If, however, the child was unable to walk, it is assur.

I'll try and edit in the source for this soon.

Comment: I'm curious to see if you can find a source, since I also thought the halacha was so, until I actually looked it up.